# Websocker-Rails message from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, websocket

recently i'n trying to use websocket-rails gem. And i wonder is there any idea to send notifications from server to user via this gem? Form example, when something in db is updated? I know that i can for example broadcast message when new will come to controller, but is there any way to do this from outside of controller? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the following code.

```
WebsocketRails[:channel_name].trigger :event_name, data_object
```

But to send from the background (model, jobs, rake task) the websocket-rails gem requires you to install redis. You can find the instruction for that in the link below.

https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Multiple-Servers-and-Background-Jobs

Comment: can i in any way identify users and send message to want not with broadcast? can i use channel_name to do this?

Comment: yes. you can give the user a private channel to his name and send messages to him. Make the private channel name some sort of hash and random so that it would be hard to guess.